# Unable to connect to Amazon web service mysql instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I went through these instructions:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/GettingStartedGuide/

But still can't connect to the database using mysql from the command line.

I even tried:
telnet xxxxxxx.clpkcufglfdn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306

but that doesn't connect either.

I did set up the DB security group using the CIDR suggested by the console (I hope it give me the right value).

Update: Firewalls are disabled on my end. It would be odd if amazon had firewalls on their end and wouldn't mention it in their documentation.

Update2: I'm behind a wireless router which had assigned my machine the IP of 10.0.0.2 so I tried adding that to the security groups but still can't connect.

Comment: Please see my comment to my answer. Your internal IP of 10.0.0.2 means absolutely nothing to Amazon, they never see it - they see your *router's* **external** IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Update: Firewalls are disabled on my end. It would be odd if amazon had firewalls on their end and wouldn't mention it in their documentation.

Amazon's security groups **are** a firewall.

> I did set up the DB security group using the CIDR suggested by the console (I hope it give me the right value).

If it's not the IP you're connecting from, it's not the right value.

Comment: According to this thread I should use the IP suggested by the console: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=229191&#229191

Comment: Using 10.0.0.2/0 ended up working so that other thread was incorrect.

Comment: 10.* is an internal IP - it means nothing to Amazon if you're not on their network. 10.0.0.2/0 worked because /0 means "allow everything on the internet". Find out what your IP is via something like http://whatismyip.com/ and use that with a /32 on the end.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a firewall that is dropping your connection.  Either it is on your end or Amazon's end; probably need to talk to your IT group and if that isn't the issue then Amazon's group to see if you missed a step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access a RDS instance from within the same AWS datacenter you need to specify a local internal IP address (i.e. 10.x.x.x) and not the public dns/ip as your connection simply doesn't go out of the lan

You can find the local IP address of your EC2 box by typing: ifconfig OR checking your login name (i.e. ubuntu@10.x.x.x)

I didn't find this anywhere and wasted a lot of time. I hope this helps!